# How to loop through a list in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a list lets say:

```
dataSet$mixed_bag <- list("Hello", c("USA", "Red", "100"), c("India", "Blue", "76"))
```

I want to iterate through this list and create new variables based on the contents of the list. 
A pseudo code would look something like this.

```
foreach row in dataSet$mixed_bag {
    if (sapply(dataSet$mixed_bag, length) == 3) {
        dataSet$country <- dataSet$mixed_bag[[row]][1];
        dataSet$color <- dataSet$mixed_bag[[row]][2];
        dataSet$score <- dataSet$mixed_bag[[row]][3];
    } else if (sapply(dataSet$mixed_bag, length) == 2) {
       #Do something else
    } else {
       # Do nothing
    }
}
```

Please suggest how would I do this in R

Comment: Did you try `lapply`?

Comment: I did. I am new to R. So, I don't know how to frame the right syntax with an iterator variable (in this case: row)
If you have an answer, please post it as an answer below.

Comment: Can you add output of `dput(dataSet)` to the post?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do inside the loop.. did you mean to write `length(dataSet$mixed_bag[[row]])` instead of `sapply(dataSet$mixed_bag, length)` ? The condition in `if` makes no sense the way it is written, because it is comparing a vector to a value and in this case you will get a warning that only the first element of the vector is used.

Comment: yes. I meant length(dataSet$mixed_bag[[row]])

Answer (score 58):

something like this?

```
dataList <- list("Hello", c("USA", "Red", "100"), c("India", "Blue", "76"))
for(i in dataList)
  {print(i)}
```

returns:

```
[1] "Hello"
[1] "USA" "Red" "100"
[1] "India" "Blue"  "76"
```

or:

```
for(i in dataList)
  {
  for(j in i)
  {print(j)}
  }
```

returns:

```
[1] "Hello"
[1] "USA"
[1] "Red"
[1] "100"
[1] "India"
[1] "Blue"
[1] "76"
```